# A way to gracefully unload AppDomain with an infinite loop running inside of it

Tags: c#, multithreading

Good afternoon (and merry xmas),

## The issue

I'm running a `dynamically compiled assembly` inside of a separate `AppDomain` in my program and I'm looking for a way to `gracefully` unload that AppDomain, without having to put it on a separate thread and forcing it to Abort (which also throws an exception).

Here's the code I use to build and terminate domains:

```
case ConduitPacketType.Execute:
    var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(name);
    domain.ExecuteAssembly(path);    
    runningDomains.Add(name, domain);

    break;
case ConduitPacketType.Terminate:
    AppDomain.Unload(runningDomains[name]);

    break;
```

The issue with that code is, the `assembly` loaded into this `domain` is nothing but an infinite loop and `AppDomain.Unload` will thus infinitely wait for it to finish.
Is there anything I could do from the inside or outside of that assembly? Perhaps an eventhandler I can hook to inside of the assembly, something like `AssemblyUnloadRequested` or something?

## Sidenote

I've also tried putting `domain.ExecuteAssembly` into a thread, then aborting the thread - but I get an exception aswell.

If there is no graceful way, I'll just terminate thread and move on.

Thanks in advance.

## Code from suggestion #1 - Failed

### Hooking to DomainUnload event inside of the assembly.

```
public class PrintSpammer
{
    public static bool IsUnloading = false;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += new EventHandler((o, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UNLOADING MARKED?");
            IsUnloading = true;
        });

        while (!IsUnloading)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(IsUnloading);

            Console.WriteLine("SPAM!");

            Thread.Sleep(750);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps catch the [`DomainUnload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.domainunload?view=netframework-4.7.2) event in the code that is running the loop, set a flag and then and exit the loop?

Comment: @DavidG So basically what I said, a hook inside of the assembly?

Comment: Yeah, seems a lot more graceful than trying to kill things externally.

Comment: @DavidG I've just tried, the event never gets called - I'll update the post with code I've tried using.

Comment: Hmm how about using the `SetData` and `GetData` methods on the app domain?

Comment: @DavidG Just tested this and the previous method again.
I've noticed that ExecuteAssembly puts a lock on the current thread, meaning my switch was actually freezing at:
`domain.ExecuteAssembly(path); `, so I've thrown it into a Task and re-tried the first method and the last one you've mentioned with GetData, in result it does unload but I get this exception now: `The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded.`